# Gambio GX and jQuery

Tags: jquery, gambio

I'm developing a template for the shopsystem Gambio GX and I encountered some problems concerning Mootols and the jQuery library.

I want to integrate a content slider on the frontpage. At first I used a Mootools solution, but then I noticed, that Gambio already comes with a jQuery library and uses it for its own stuff, which resulted in neither Mootools nor jQuery working together properly. So I decided to stick to jQuery in my template and found [that content slider tutorial](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/featured-content-slider-using-jquery-ui/).

Unfortunately, it works fine running alone, but within the template it simply does nothing except for displaying the pictures (there should be an animation).
I suppose, the problem might regard the external libraries loaded by the script at runtime:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.5.3/jquery-ui.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#featured > ul").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

I thought there might be some problems caused by the two different versions of the library (Gambio uses jQuery 1.2.4a natively and locally), but omitting those two requests didn't change anything.

I'm totally stuck and I hope somebody may have an idea what's going wrong there!
Thanks in advance!